# performing a unique transaction in sqlite3 php

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, unique

i have an sqlite3 database accessed using php,to which users insert and update rows simultaneously(multi-threaded).
In order to avoid data corruption(and inaccurate results resulted from multiple connections and changes to the same row at the same time),i read about sqlite's unique transaction(http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).
however,i am not sure if i implimented it properly.i am using phppdo.

```
$conn->beginTransaction();
$conn->exec("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION");
//
//..a few insert and update queries

$db.commit();
```

as i understand it,a transaction is in the DEFFERED state by default.
My question is - does the code i enclosed actually convert/create an exclusive transaction, and in case it does not - how do i accomplish that?

Thanks,

edit:
would this work?

```
$conn->exec("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION");
//insert and update queries
$conn->exec("COMMIT");
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)?

Comment: yes i have.i am not sure,however,if the syntax i used(creating a transaction,and afterwards calling exec) - works.